# grep whole server for shell hacks/malware

Tags: php, linux, security, shell, grep

We host 1000s of domains on multiple servers. We have problems with massive amount of  malware  and phpshell's. The usage of many scanners had no effect in taking them down. maybe we got 10/20 vague results from those scanners

so i build my own little bash file to find those scripts. 
It found 148 phpshells this weekend ( im not that good at creating .SH files).

**My question**
The grep is terrible slow, it will run for days. how can i make this script more efficient?

```
array=(
    "base64_decode(" 
    "substr(md5(strrev(" 
    "cwd = @getcwd();" 
    "chr((ord(" 
    "gzinflate(base64_decode(" 
    "php_uname()" "] = chr(ord(" 
    "cwd[strlen($cwd)" 
    "ini_get('safe_mode');" 
    "=\"\x62\"" 
    "\"+ r + \"&r=\" + document.referrer;\"" 
    "if(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) ) == \"WIN\")" 
    "window.top.location.href=\"http://" 
    "@ini_get(\"disable_functions\")" 
    "$g3='';$g3.=$r;$g3.=$h;$g3.=$y"
    "hacked"
)

for value in "${array[@]}"
do
    printf "\n[$value] [start => $(date +"%T")]\n"
        grep -l -inr "$value" "/home/"
    printf "\n[end => $(date +"%T")]\n"
done
```

**FINAL RESULT**

```
#!/bin/bash
LC_ALL=C grep -F -n -r -f /root/scanner/pattern.txt "/home/"
```

**Pattern.txt**

```
eval($___($__));
eval(stripslashes(@$_POST[
eval(stripslashes(array_pop(
eval(base64_decode(
eval(gzinflate(str_rot13(base64_decode(
gzinflate(base64_decode(
Array(base64_decode(
sha1(base64_decode(
print(base64_decode(
wsoScandir($dir)
substr(current(array_keys(
cwd = @getcwd();
$OOO000000=urldecode(
$l___l_='base'.(32*2)
substr(md5(strrev(
cwd[strlen($cwd)
="x62
+ r + "&r=" + document.referrer;
if(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) ) == "WIN")
){if(@copy(
copy("endless.html
system("wget
symlink("/","sym/root");
@copy($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
error_reporting(0);if(
x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69
"/.*/e","\x28\x65\x76\x61
preg_replace("/.*/e",
Windows-1251";preg_replace(
); exit(); } if(isset(
system("$cmd"); die;}
rtrim($security_code, "/");
```

Comment: It might be better performance wise to do a full scan once and after that keep track of changed files and only scan those.

Comment: yes, i want that too. only i need the script to end fully. now it go's  50% and the process gets stuck. 

what i also found was shellhacks that use the php 'touch' command to change the 'date modified' field of a file.

Comment: You could limit your script to only look into text files, so it will skip pictures n stuff.

Comment: @DanFromGermany In my experience image files are also used to put code in.

Comment: @PeeHaa sure and you can configure PHP to interpret whatever file ending you want, but still I think looking into EVERY file is not the way to go. Try php,txt,htm,html,js first, then do a run on other files. Or, if you host so many domains, buy something like WatchGuard..

Comment: One suggestion, it will not save too much time, but it will be helpful. If you need the file name only, and no care which rules to be detected. So after find one in list, maybe you can exclude it or exclude that whole domain in next round of loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store your search strings as a single multiline string, and run fgrep once instead of in a loop:

```
values="eval(base64_decode(
gzinflate(base64_decode(
cwd = @getcwd();
chr((ord(
substr(md5(strrev(
chr(ord(
cwd[strlen(\$cwd)
ini_get('safe_mode');
=\"\x62\"
\"+ r + \"&r=\" + document.referrer;\"
if(strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) ) == \"WIN\")
window.top.location.href=\"http://
@ini_get(\"disable_functions\")
){if(@copy(
eval(\$___(\$__));
copy(\"endless.html\"
system(\"wget
symlink(\"/\",\"sym/root\");
@copy(\$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
error_reporting(0);if(
x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74
hacked"

LC_ALL=C fgrep -nr --include  \*.php "$values" *
```

This version runs 22x faster than the original (0.535s vs 11.817s on one fairly large site). Noncoincidentally, you have 22 search strings.

PS: Don't forget to \ your $ inside of "", or you won't find your 15th and 19th search strings. I would create a test file that has all the strings you're searching for, and verify that the fgrep "$values" successfully matches each of them.

Comment: My endresults look a lot like yours! i posted it after succesfull cleaning, even watchguard did not remove them. kinda fun :)

Comment: Actually, your answer is a better, since you avoid having to \ "s and $s :)